# How do you get a bloodthirsty medal with a crossbow?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

In order to get gold camo for the crossbow, one of the challenges is that you need to get a bloodthirsty medal using only the crossbow.

A bloodthirsty medal is obtained by getting 5 kills in a row, without dying.

I have been trying to get this for a long time. Attempting to use the crossbow without the tri-bolt attachment to get the medal is extremely difficult. I instead have been trying to use scavenger with the tri-bolt attachment. I still have had no luck.

What is the easiest way to complete this challenge?

Comment: I'd say try to find where people camp. If you can be sure every time you come to that place, someone is there, you high up your chances of getting kills. For example, the windows on the first floor of both houses in Nuketown can get you pretty easy kills with the crossbow. Also, I would drop the try-bolt attachment and scavenger, because if you don't find a scavenger pack, you only get 2 shots, and in BO2, scavenger packs are only dropped by enemies you personally killed, so... Take your time, and maybe try to go around their spawn and get them from behind, you'll have more time to aim right.

Comment: Try hardcore. Easier to kill people

Comment: Easier to die too though :)

Comment: I don't think scavenger packs are only dropped from enemies you kill, but I can't be sure. They seem to be extremely rare, which is extremely frustrating.

Comment: If I remember correctly from this video (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mvoH9EzDdqo), in team based games, they are only dropped by enemies you killed. Scavenger now works really differently, I'd recommend you watch the video to understand everything.

Comment: @rdurand Easier to die only applies if you don't get the jump on people. I agree hardcore is far easier to get killstreaks if you learn to be patient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a video that talks a little bit about it. It talks a little bit about setup and what map to use. It recommends sticks and stones. Other objective based maps will do as well like things like dominations.

For setup he does:

- reflex scope
- lightweight  (you can pick something else ghost is also good)
- scavenger (wont work if you kill with explosives)
- dexterity (crossbow aim is slow so its important)

Hopefully this is enough information to get it yourself. If not I hope it at least gives you enough motivation from this to get it.

Comment: Is scavenger really relevant ? As I stated in my comment and as you said in your answer, it doesn't seem useful at all here..

Comment: This answer leaves a lot to be desired. There are no custom classes in Sticks and Stones. He recommends doing sticks and stones in order to get to the point where you need the bloodthirsty. At that point it seems he recommends playing a core or hardcore game type because he talks about how useful scavenger is and the problem of direct impact vs explosive kills. There is no scavenger in sticks and stones so he cant be recommending it for the bloodthirsty.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I just waited until I was on level that I knew I could camp at or you can work the perimeter of each level.

Comment: What level is that?

Answer (score 0):

Play capture the flag and just camp around a flag. Take caution to be in a place where no one can see you then start practicing your aim, so you could find the scopes that suits you better.

Comment: This answer is a little brief, can you expand upon it?